# TextBlock as CheckBox content not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an issue with a Check Box in WPF. I'm trying to set a CheckBox's content explicity to a TextBlock, so I can then set the TextBlock's foreground without affecting the check in the box.

I'm doing this to a CheckBox in a StackPanel full of check boxes in a data grid templated column, like so:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Effectivity" CellStyle="{StaticResource WhiteForeground}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander x:Name="EffectivityExpander" Header="{Binding EffectivityString}" Style="{StaticResource DisableExpander}" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Path=Foreground}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock Text="Next order" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, Path=Foreground}" />
                    </CheckBox>
                    <CheckBox Content="Parts on order" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The issue is that the first check box in the example XAML doesn't show any text when run, while the second one does. When using VS 2015's Live Property Explorer on the two check boxes, the first one shows it Text property under Computed Values/Templated Parent/Content, and the second one (that displays) shows its text as a local value.

I've tried removing the bindings and styles to see if they had any effect and it still didn't show.

Does anyone have any insight as to why the first TextBlock isn't displaying?

EDIT:
To respond to people's questions, It's not just the foreground color. Using VS2015's "Live Visual Tree" selector, there's no text to select.

See this screenshot (or snipping thereof):
[image: Selection of second item]

Selecting the text box for the first one in the visual tree shows no border in the app. Also, hovering where the text would be does not allow me to check the box; clicks go through to the Expander. Moving the mouse around in the running app appears to show a one-pixel wide area next to the check box itself that does allow interaction with the box, at the beginning of what would have been the TextBlock. It's as if the TextBlock had no text.

Comment: What does Live Property Explorer say the value of the first TextBlock's `Foreground` property is?  Is it perhaps the same color as the background of the cell?

Comment: Try remove the Foreground attribute from the TextBlock and see if the text appears when you run it. Don't trust "Live Visual Tree" - I've seen cases when it fails. Something doesn't add up here - using a TextBlock as the content of a CheckBox works fine for me.

Comment: I already tried removing styles and even bindings from things all the way up the chain to the datagrid itself, the textblock didn't show. Inspection with Snoop rather than VS2015 showed that textblock as having all its values default (thus no text). Perhaps it's something to do with Modern UI for WPF?

Answer (score 3):

You might be using white foreground which might be making the text appearing as white hence can't be seen.

[image: Screen shot when run]

Here is the code :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDataGrid._32635114.Win32635114"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Win32635114" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="WhiteForeground">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Expander" x:Key="DisableExpander">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="BurlyWood"/>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" Height="270" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Effectivity" CellStyle="{StaticResource WhiteForeground}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander x:Name="EffectivityExpander" Header="{Binding EffectivityString}" Style="{StaticResource DisableExpander}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <CheckBox>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Next order" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" />
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <CheckBox Content="Parts on order" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
namespace WpfDataGrid._32635114
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Win32635114.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Win32635114 : Window
    {
        public Win32635114()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataStore store = new DataStore();
            this.DataContext = store;
        }
    }
}
```

DataStore.cs

```
    namespace WpfDataGrid._32635114
{
    public class DataStore
    {
        private List<Record> _values;
        public List<Record> Values { get { return _values; } }

        public DataStore() {
            _values = new List<Record>();
            _values.Add(new Record() { EffectivityString = "somestring1" });
            _values.Add(new Record() { EffectivityString = "somestring2" });
            _values.Add(new Record() { EffectivityString = "somestring3" });
            _values.Add(new Record() { EffectivityString = "somestring4" });
        }
    }

    public class Record
    {
        public String EffectivityString { get; set; }
    }
}
```